# OnItemClicklistener returning somthing else

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String rId = ds.child("Phone_Number").getValue(String.class);
                String name = ds.child("Name").getValue(String.class);

                al.add(name);
                al.add(rId);
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, al);
            ListView listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            mProgressDialogue.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Check Your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

    usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //This cannot be done in this way

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class);
            String rId = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String name = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            intent.putExtra("Recievers_Id", rId);
            intent.putExtra("Recievers_Name", name);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
```

It's like. In the listview... Of the same user userid and name is shown... Ik y that is shown. Its because I hav added al.add (name) and also id... That's becuase... In onclicklistener I want to fetch id of the user but the listview should contain names... I'm not able to do that... Like if I click on the name of the user it fetches name and if I click on id of the user it fetches id... I want it to work like... IF I CLICK ON NAME OF THE USER IT SHOULD FETCH ID

Comment: what is shown in the listview?

Comment: I just want to show the users names... but if i click on the names rID is returning name... so i put numbers... if i click on it now it returns the numbers.... but i want it to return numbers even whn i click on names

Comment: Do you have a model class that you are using to add data to the database? If yes, please add the code and also the database structure.

Comment: No there's no database... and yeah this is the code u gave a few days back

Comment: Please responde with @ How are you adding data to the database, not using a model class? Please share the model class and your database structure.